# Solutions for floating point rounding errors

Tags: floating-point, numeric-precision

In building an application that deals with a lot of mathematical calculations, I have encountered the problem that certain numbers cause rounding errors.

While I understand that [floating point is not exact](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors), the problem is *how* do I deal with exact numbers to make sure that when calculations are preformed on them floating point rounding doesn't cause any issues?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are facing?  There are many ways to do testing, all right for some problem.  Questions that can have multiple answers are a poor fit for the Q&A format.  It would be best if you could define the problem you are having in a way that could have one right answer rather than casting a net for ideas and recommendations.

Comment: I am building a Software Application with lot of mathematical caluclations. I understand NUNIT or JUNIT testing would be good, but would love to have an idea on how to approach the issues with Mathematical Calulations.

Comment: Can you give an example of a calculation you would be testing? One typically wouldn't be unit testing raw math (unless you are testing your own numerical types), but testing something like `distanceTraveled(startVel, duration, acceleration)` would be tested.

Comment: One example will be dealing with decimal points. For example, say we  are building a wall with special settings for dist x-0 to x=14.589 and then some arrangements from x=14.589 to x=end of the wall. The distance .589 when converted into binary are not the same....Especially if we add some distances...like 14.589+0.25 will not be equal to 14.84 in binary....I hope its not confusing?

Comment: Not at all (my previous employment dealing with money had exactly these problems).  You have two problems, the first is the numeric type and floating point rounding... the second is making sure the calculations are as expected.  Give me a bit, and I'll modify this question to reflect the numeric problem you are having.

Comment: Are you dealing with algorithms that are nondeterministic?

Comment: @JeffO I do deal with Algorithms but not much. Would love to move in that direction.

Comment: @MichaelT thank you for editing the Question. Helped a lot. Since am new to this, not too good on how to frame the questions. :) ...But will be good soon.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are three fundamental approaches to creating alternative numeric types that are free of floating point rounding.  The common theme with these is that they use integer math instead in various ways.

**Rationals**

Represent the number as a whole part and rational number with a numerator and a denominator. The number `15.589` would be represented as `w: 15; n: 589; d:1000`.

When added to 0.25 (which is `w: 0; n: 1; d: 4`), this involves calculating the LCM, and then adding the two numbers.  This works well for many situations, though can result in very large numbers when you are working with many rational numbers that are relatively prime to each other.

**Fixed point**

You have the whole part, and the decimal part.  All numbers are rounded (there's that word - but you know where it is) to that precision.  For example, you could have fixed point with 3 decimal points.  `15.589` + `0.250` becomes adding `589 + 250 % 1000` for the decimal part (and then any carry to the whole part).  This works very nicely with existing databases.  As mentioned, there is rounding but you know where it is and can specify it such that it is more precise than is needed (you are only measuring to 3 decimal points, so make it fixed 4).

**Floating fixed point**

Store a value and the precision.  `15.589` is stored as `15589` for the value and `3` for the precision, while `0.25` is stored as `25` and `2`.  This can handle arbitrary precision. I *believe* this is what the internals of Java's BigDecimal uses (haven't looked at it recently) uses. At some point, you will want to get it back out of this format and display it - and that may involve rounding (again, you control where it is).

---

Once you determine the choice for the representation, you can either find existing third party libraries that use this, or write your own.  When writing your own, be sure to unit test it and make sure you are doing the math correctly.

Comment: That's a good start, but of course it doesn't completely solve the rounding problem. Irrational numbers like π, *e* and √2 don't have a strictly numeric representation; you need to represent them symbolically if you want an exact representation, or evaluate them as late as possible if you just want to minimize the rounding error.

Comment: @Caleb for irrationals one would need to evaluate them to beyond where any rounding could cause problems. For example, 22/7 is accurate to 0.1% of pi, 355/113 is accurate to 10^-8. If you are only working with numbers to 3 decimal places, having 3.141592653 should avoid any rounding errors at 3 decimal places.

Comment: @MichaelT: For addition of rational numbers you don't need to find the LCM and it's faster not to (and faster to cancel "LSB zeros" after, and only ever fully simplify when absolutely necessary). For rational numbers in general it's typically just "numerator/denominator" alone, or "numerator/denominator << exponent" (and not "whole part + numerator/denominator"). Also your "floating fixed point" is a floating point representation, and would be better described as "arbitrary size floating point" (to distinguish it from "fixed size floating point").

Comment: some of your terminology is a bit iffy - floating fixed point makes no sense - I think you are trying to say floating decimal.

Answer (score 12):

If floating point values have rounding problems, and you don't want to have to run into rounding problems, it logically follows that the only course of action is to not use floating point values.

Now the question becomes, "how do I do math involving non-integer values without floating point variables?"  The answer is with [arbitrary-precision data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).  Calculations are slower because they have to be implemented in software instead of in hardware, but they're accurate.  You didn't say what language you're using, so I can't recommend a package, but there are arbitrary precision libraries available for most popular programming languages.

Comment: I am using VC++ right now... But I would appreciate any more information regarding other programming languages too.

Comment: Even without floating point values you're still going to run into round problems.

Comment: @Chad True, but the goal is not to eliminate rounding problems (which will always exist, because in any base you use there are some numbers that have no exact representation, and you don't have infinite memory and processing power), it's to reduce it to the point it has no effect in the calculation you are trying to do.

Comment: @Iker You're right. Though you, nor the person asking the question have specified what exactly calculations they're trying to achieve and the precision they want. He needs to answer that question first before jumping the gun into number theory. Just saying `lot of mathematical calculations` isn't helpful nor the answers given. In the vast majority of the case (if you're not dealing with currency) then float should really suffice.

Comment: @Chad that's a fair point, there's certainly not enough data from the OP to tell what exactly is the precision level they need.

Answer (score 9):

Floating point arithmetic is usually quite precise (15 decimal digits for a `double`) and quite flexible. The problems crop up when you are doing math that significantly reduces the amount of digits of precision. Here are some examples:

- Cancelation on subtraction: `1234567890.12345 - 1234567890.12300`, the result `0.0045` has only two decimal digits of precision. This strikes whenever you subtract two numbers of similar magnitude.
- Swallowing of precision: `1234567890.12345 + 0.123456789012345` evaluates to `1234567890.24691`, the last ten digits of the second operand are lost.
- Multiplications: If you multiply two 15 digit numbers, the result has 30 digits that need to be stored. But you can't store them, so the last 15 bits are lost. This is especially irksome when combined with a `sqrt()` (as in `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`: The result will only have 7.5 digits of precision.

These are the main pitfalls that you need to be aware of. And once you are aware of them, you can try to formulate your math in a way that avoids them. For examle, if you need to increment a value over and over again in a loop, avoid doing this:

```
for(double f = f0; f < f1; f += df) {
```

After a few iterations, the larger `f` will swallow part of the precision of `df`. Worse, the errors will add up, leading to the contraintuitive situation that a smaller `df` may lead to worse overall results. Better write this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (f1 - f0)/df; i++) {
    double f = f0 + i*df;
```

Because you are combining the increments in a single multiplication, the resulting `f` will be precise to 15 decimal digits.

This is only an example, there are other ways to avoid loss of precision due to other reasons. But it helps already a lot to think about the magnitude of the involved values, and to imagine what would happen if you were to do your math with pen and paper, rounding to a fixed number of digits after every step.

Answer (score 2):

How to make sure that you don't have problems: Learn about floating-point arithmetic problems, or hire someone who does, or use some common sense.

The first problem is precision. In many languages you have "float" and "double" (double standing for "double precision"), and in many cases "float" gives you about 7 digits precision, while double gives you 15. Common sense is that if you have a situation where precision might be a problem, 15 digits is an awful lot better than 7 digits. In many slightly problematic situations, using "double" means you get away with it, and "float" means you don't. Let's say a company's market caps is 700 billion dollars. Represent this in float, and the lowest bit is $65536. Represent it using double, and the lowest bit is about 0.012 cents. So unless you really, really know what you are doing, you use double, not float.

The second problem is more a matter of principle. If you do two different calculations that should give the same result, they often don't because of rounding errors. Two result that should be equal will be "almost equal". If two results are close together, then the real values might be equal. Or they might be not. You need to keep that in mind and should write and use functions that say "x is definitely greater than y" or "x is definitely less than y" or "x and y might be equal".

This problem gets a lot worse if you use rounding, for example "round x down to the nearest integer". If you multiply 120 * 0.05, the result should be 6, but what you get is "some number very close to 6". If you then "round down to the nearest integer", that "number very close to 6" might be "slightly less than 6" and get rounded to 5. And note that it doesn't matter how much precision you have. Doesn't matter *how close* to 6 your result is, as long as it is less than 6.

And third, some problems are *difficult*. That means there is no quick and easy rule. If your compiler supports "long double" with more precision you can use "long double" and see if it makes a difference. If it makes no difference, then either you are Ok, or you have a real tricky problem. If it makes the kind of difference that you would expect (like a change at the 12th decimal) then you are likely alright. If it really changes your results, then you have a problem. Ask for help.

Comment: There is nothing "common sense" about floating point math.

Comment: Learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most people make the mistake when they see double they scream BigDecimal, when in fact
they've just moved the problem elsewhere. Double gives Sign bit: 1 bit, Exponent width: 11 bits.
Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored). Due to the nature of double, the larger
the whole interger you lose relative accuracy. To calculate the relative accuracy we use here
is bellow.

Relative accuracy of double in the calculation we use the following foluma
2^E <= abs(X) < 2^(E+1)

epsilon = 2^(E-10)    % For a 16-bit float (half precision)

```
 Accuracy Power | Accuracy -/+| Maximum Power | Max Interger Value
 2^-1           | 0.5         | 2^51          | 2.2518E+15
 2^-5           | 0.03125     | 2^47          | 1.40737E+14
 2^-10          | 0.000976563 | 2^42          | 4.39805E+12
 2^-15          | 3.05176E-05 | 2^37          | 1.37439E+11
 2^-20          | 9.53674E-07 | 2^32          | 4294967296
 2^-25          | 2.98023E-08 | 2^27          | 134217728
 2^-30          | 9.31323E-10 | 2^22          | 4194304
 2^-35          | 2.91038E-11 | 2^17          | 131072
 2^-40          | 9.09495E-13 | 2^12          | 4096
 2^-45          | 2.84217E-14 | 2^7           | 128
 2^-50          | 8.88178E-16 | 2^2           | 4
```

In other words 
If you want a Accuracy of +/-0.5 (or 2^-1), the maximum size that the number can be is 2^52. 
Any larger than this and the distance between floating point numbers is greater than 0.5.

If you want an accuracy of +/-0.0005 (about 2^-11), the maximum size that the number can be 
is 2^42. Any larger than this and the distance between floating point numbers is greater than 0.0005.

I cannot really give a better answer than this. The user will need figure out what precision they want when performing the necessary calculation and their unit value (Meters, Feet, Inches, mm, cm). For the vast majority of cases float will suffice for simple simulations depending on the scale of the world you're aiming to simulate.

Though it is something to be said, if you're only aiming to simulate a 100 meter by 100 meter world you're going to have somewhere in the order of accuracy near 2^-45. This is not even going into how modern FPU inside cpu's will do calculations outside of the native type size and only after the calculation is complete they will round (depending on the FPU rounding mode) to the native type size.